# Как переопределить скролл в css / js

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка

интересует возможность переопределения скролла. Вообще как, мне нужно чтоб человек плавно перемещался по сайту по якорям, без нажатия кнопок, как обычный скролл, это реализовано на  [этом сайте](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ru/), интересует возможность сделать также только без jquery на нативном js или css. В этой сфере новичок, так что не знаю пока многих своиств и возможностей.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Можно без JS и CSS, но быстро и не плавно.

Comment: Хорошо, но мне нужно плавно.

Comment: для плавности можно добавить css `scroll-behaviour`

Comment: да я понимаю о чем речь, сам видел такие сайты. Это делается при помощи html якорей + немного js, ну и css свойство для плавности которое я написал выше. Нужно как-то отловить пользовательский скролл, что не легко. Нужно копать в этом направлении

Comment: вот тут есть инфа как предотвратить скролл и самому его инициировать на столько пикселей на сколько тебе нужно (до следующего якоря) https://learn.javascript.ru/onscroll

Comment: "Нельзя предотвратить прокрутку, используя event.preventDefault() в обработчике onscroll, потому что он срабатывает после того, как прокрутка уже произошла." - с сайта же.

Это я и сам находил, проблема в том что кроме как overflow прокрутку никак не залочить, а если её лочить через overflow то там вообще нельзя будет прокручивать.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type

Comment: Ты лучший, спасибо тебе! Можешь написать в ответы чтоб я тебе галочку дал?